# PostgreSQL Bulk Copy with PowerShell

Tags: postgresql, powershell, copy, bulk

There is no Bulk Copy on PostgreSQL that I know and I struggled to find anything on the web. The only effective solution was a PS Module, but it has a paid license.

So I started playing with the PostgreSQL ODBC driver and came up with a function that accepts a PSCustomObject and copies it to the database using the COPY statement.

There one drawback and I'll be more than glad to hear your opinion on:

- The function exports the Data Table as a CSV file and then uses the COPY statement to up this info.

The code can be found bellow and on the PS Gallery:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Write-PsqlDataTable/1.0.1

```
Function Write-PsqlDataTable
{

    [CmdletBinding()] 
    param(

        [Parameter  (Position = 0, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]    $ServerInstance,

        [Parameter  (Mandatory = $false)]
        [int]       $Port=5432,

        [Parameter  (Position = 1, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]    $Database,

        [Parameter  (Position = 2, Mandatory = $true)]
        [string]    $TableName,

        [Parameter  (Position = 3, Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Data.DataTable] $Data,
                    
        [Parameter  (Position = 4, Mandatory = $false)] 
        [string]    $Username,

        [Parameter  (Position = 5, Mandatory = $false)]
        [Security.SecureString] $Password,

        [Parameter  (Mandatory = $false)]
        [string]    $Docker

    ) 
     
    
    $DBConn = New-Object System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
    $BTSR = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($Password)
    $PTP = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto($BTSR)
    if ($Username) {
        $DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$ServerInstance;Port=$Port;Database=$Database;Uid=$Username;Pwd=$PTP;"
    } 
    else {
        $DBConnectionString = "Driver={PostgreSQL UNICODE(x64)};Server=$ServerInstance;Port=$Port;Database=$Database;"
    } 
 
    $DBConn.ConnectionString = $DBConnectionString
         
    try 
    {
        $Columns = $Data.Columns.ColumnName
        $Columns = [System.String]::Join(',',$Columns)
        $Data | Export-Csv $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
        if ($Docker) {
            docker cp $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv "$($Docker):/media/TempPsAd.csv"
            $DBConn.Open()
            $DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand()
            $DBCmd.CommandText = @"
                COPY $TableName ($Columns)
                FROM '/media/TempPsAd.csv'
                DELIMITER ','
                CSV HEADER
"@
            $DBCmd.ExecuteReader()
            $DBConn.Close()
            docker exec $Docker rm -rf /media/TempPsAd.csv
            Remove-Item $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv -Force
        }
        else {
            $DBConn.Open()
            $DBCmd = $DBConn.CreateCommand()
            $DBCmd.CommandText = @"
                COPY $TableName ($Columns)
                FROM '$Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv'
                DELIMITER ','
                CSV HEADER
"@
            $DBCmd.ExecuteReader()
            $DBConn.Close()
            Remove-Item $Env:TEMP\TempPsAd.csv -Force
        }
        
    } 
    catch 
    { 
        Write-Error "$($_.Exception.Message)"
        continue 
    } 
}
```

**Edit:**

Using Data Table to solve the Column issue. 
Here's what the input data would look like:

```
$ADDevices = Get-ADComputer @ADDeviceArgs
$DataTable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
foreach ($Property in $ADDeviceArgs.Properties) {
    $Property = $Property -replace '^', 'add_'
    $DataTable.Columns.Add($Property) | Out-Null
}
foreach ($Device in $ADDevices) {
    $Rows = $DataTable.NewRow()
    $Rows['add_name'] = $Device.Name
    $Rows['add_enabled'] = $Device.Enabled
    $Rows['add_lastlogontimestamp'] = [datetime]::FromFileTime($Device.lastlogontimestamp)
    $Rows['add_modifytimestamp'] = $Device.modifytimestamp
    $Rows['add_distinguishedname'] = $Device.distinguishedname
    $Rows['add_objectguid'] = $Device.objectguid
    $Rows['add_description'] = $Device.description
    $DataTable.Rows.Add($Rows)
}
```

Comment: Instead of using Get-Member, why not do `$Data.PSObject.Properties.Name`, which will give you the properties in the correct order of the PsCustomObject.

Comment: I tried and returned the result ordered for me too. I was fighting it for a while before giving up lol

Comment: No No, you are absolutely correct. Retried here and it worked. I'm editing the post. Thanks man!

Comment: So you can remove that drawback _needs to be alphabetically ordered_ I guess ;)

Comment: Bad news, i cannot make it work with a PsCustomObject because it have NoteProperties and they are in `$Object.PsCustomObject.Properties.Value` With all the other values. how do i select only them?

Comment: @Theo came back to bring the good news. Data Table was the answer.